# Apex REST API "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST" Issue

Tags: rest-api, api, apexrest, url, postman

We have created an Apex REST API which is using POST method. when we consume the API from postman with below URL,

https://TestDomain--pcsandbox.**my.salesforce.com**/services/apexrest/v1/updateAll

but when we use https://TestDomain--pcsandbox.**lightning.force.com**/services/apexrest/v1/updateAll

we are getting below error,

```
[
    {

        "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",

        "message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST"
    }
]
```

Any pointers on what could be the issue here ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured a `POST` request in Postman? As the error message says, Postman appears to be submitting a `GET` request to the API.

Comment: Yes, it is set to POST as you can see it's working with other URL.

Comment: So you have enabled MyDomain. Are you saying that you expect the `REST` service located in the `https://TestDomain--pcsandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/v1/updateAll` domain to be available when you change the target URL from Postman?

Comment: Yes MyDomain is enabled. The issue here is because of the different salesforce URL force.com and Salesforce.com. force.com is supporting only GET Method it seems as it work for get method. however, saleforce.com is working for both GET and POST.

Comment: If you are trying the method in POSTMAN and forgot to 'https://' in end point, It will always consider as 'GET' instead of 'POST'.